# Recorded macro for data labels does not work

Tags: vba, excel, charts

So, I'm a novice at using VBA but not so new that I know not to use .select and the likes wherever possible but I will still record macros to find out how to call certain objects. I am working on a large piece of code to do various things before manipulating a chart at the end, it wasn't working so breaking it down into a new spreadsheet I found that some of my lines for manipulating chart labels were giving me an error. I recorded a macro to make sure I hadn't mis-typed anything, but could not fix it, then tried to run the recorded macro, but couldn't get it to work.

Heres the aim of my code:
1. Apply data labels to one point in a series.
2. Delete the label I just applied

(in the final code there will be "if" functions ect)

Here is the macro code, straight from the recorder:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).ApplyDataLabels
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.ShowValue = 0
Selection.ShowCategoryName = -1 
' this line ^ gives error 438, object does not support this property or method
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.Delete
```

What's also very curious is that sometimes rather than Selection.ShowValue = 0 it will use Selection.ShowValue = False

Anyone know why the recorded code for this is so jumpy? Also if anyone could suggest simpler code for manipulating data labels that would be very useful.
I am using excel 07 on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charts in VBA have always been a pain in the rear for me. That being said, here's some code that tosses a few of the more common objects into variables (so you can break the code on a line and see what's going on in the "locals" window). This will iterate through all of the points on your chart and add a datalabel containing the "Value".

```
Sub test()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject 'A "ChartObject" contains a Chart, in which the "SeriesCollection" resides
    Dim chartSeries As Series 'Multiple "Series" can be found in a "SeriesCollection"
    Dim scPoint As Point

    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    Set chartSeries = myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1) 'Get the first "Series" in the "SeriesCollection" for this chart

    'loop through the points in this Series. As it loops the point will be available in the "scPoint" variable. 
    For Each scPoint In chartSeries.Points
        With scPoint.DataLabel 'Finally the "DataLabel" is part of the "Point"
            .ShowValue = True 'Just show the value. There are other options here, just create a new line and start typing with a period to see what other options are available for a "DataLabel"
        End With
    Next scPoint

    'Instead of iterating, if you just want to address a single point's datalabel then:
    chartSeries.Points(2).DataLabel.ShowValue
End Sub
```